# Problema para generar reporte en Java con JasperReport

Tags: java, postgresql, netbeans-8.2, jasper-reports

Al ejecutar un reporte con parámetros, el sistema me devuelve el reporte completo como si éste no tuviese ninguno.

```
public void generar_reporte (String ruta, Map parametro) { //Reporte con parámetros 

        try {

            reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(ruta); 
            jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(ruta, parametro, conexion);

            view = new JasperViewer(jprint, false); 
            view.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            view.setVisible(true);                              

        } catch (JRException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();

        }


    }
```

```
Map<String, Object> parametro = new HashMap();

parametro.put("fecha_inicial", java.sql.Date.valueOf(fecha_inicial));
parametro.put("fecha_final", java.sql.Date.valueOf(fecha_final));


evento.generar_reporte("C:\\archivos\\reportes\\mostrar.jasper", parametro)
```

En el reporte resultante obtengo todos los datos de la tabla. No me los devuelve filtrado como debe ser. En JasperStudio funciona correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En Netbeans, al intentar generarlo, obtengo todos los datos. Además del siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías poner el código del jrxml para ayudarte mejor?

Comment: Lo que estas observando en los logs no son mensajes de error, son advertencias que no encuentra la la configuración de log4j, eso es únicamente necesario si necesitaras ver logs de jasperreports mas detallados o si quieres definir políticas como guardar los logs en un archivo. Por lo demás esos mensajes no te afectan en la ejecución.

Comment: ¿Los valores de las fechas `fecha_inicial` y `fecha_final` de dónde los obtienes?

Comment: Obtengo las fechas a través de un `JDateChooser `, que luego se convierte en String mediante `getCalendar().get(Calendar.YEAR)` , luego `MONTH`, etc. El resultado final de ejemplo sería: fecha_inicial = "2019-05-22"